# Iterate over an object returned by fetch and combine two values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, jsx

Working on recipe finder app using React & Mealdb api, below is the json retruned when I fetch, https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata.

I am struggling to work out how to iterate over this to pull together a list of the ingredients and measures. I was thinking of using a for loop but cannot write this in JSX. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{"meals":[{"idMeal":"52771","strMeal":"Spicy Arrabiata Penne","strDrinkAlternate":null,"strCategory":"Vegetarian","strArea":"Italian","strInstructions":"Bring a large pot of water to a boil. Add kosher salt to the boiling water, then add the pasta. Cook according to the package instructions, about 9 minutes.\r\nIn a large skillet over medium-high heat, add the olive oil and heat until the oil starts to shimmer. Add the garlic and cook, stirring, until fragrant, 1 to 2 minutes. Add the chopped tomatoes, red chile flakes, Italian seasoning and salt and pepper to taste. Bring to a boil and cook for 5 minutes. Remove from the heat and add the chopped basil.\r\nDrain the pasta and add it to the sauce. Garnish with Parmigiano-Reggiano flakes and more basil and serve warm.","strMealThumb":"https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/ustsqw1468250014.jpg","strTags":"Pasta,Curry","strYoutube":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=1IszT_guI08","strIngredient1":"penne rigate","strIngredient2":"olive oil","strIngredient3":"garlic","strIngredient4":"chopped tomatoes","strIngredient5":"red chile flakes","strIngredient6":"italian seasoning","strIngredient7":"basil","strIngredient8":"Parmigiano-Reggiano","strIngredient9":"","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strIngredient16":null,"strIngredient17":null,"strIngredient18":null,"strIngredient19":null,"strIngredient20":null,"strMeasure1":"1 pound","strMeasure2":"1\/4 cup","strMeasure3":"3 cloves","strMeasure4":"1 tin ","strMeasure5":"1\/2 teaspoon","strMeasure6":"1\/2 teaspoon","strMeasure7":"6 leaves","strMeasure8":"spinkling","strMeasure9":"","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","strMeasure16":null,"strMeasure17":null,"strMeasure18":null,"strMeasure19":null,"strMeasure20":null,"strSource":null,"strImageSource":null,"strCreativeCommonsConfirmed":null,"dateModified":null}]}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Can you add code which you tried to write and struggle

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Array.map() to loop through arrays in JSX components